# Extract information present within i and br tag and save in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I have HTML page where I need to extract information within the i tag and the br tag and save it in a dictionary as shown below,

```
<div class="rbody">
<div style="color:#ff6666"> </div>
<i>objectid: </i> 137000<br/>
<i>topoid: </i> 504514394<br/>
<i>poigroup: </i> Hydrography<br/>
<i>poitype: </i> Manmade Waterbody<br/>
<i>poiname: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabel: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabeltype: </i> NAMED<br/>
<i>poialtlabel: </i> <br/>
<i>Point:</i><br/>
<i>X: </i> 1.5778346701624997E7 <br/>
<i>Y: </i> -3861557.6243750006 <br/>
<br/><br/>
</div>
```

I'm able to extract the text present inside the div tag with class rbody. Even I'm able to extract the content between i tag but not the information before the br tag.  could any one suggest a method to extract the information and save it as a key value pair in a dictionary. For example

```
dictionary = {'objectid': 137000, 'topoid': 504514394, 'poigroup': 'Hydrography', 'poitype':'Manmade Waterbody', 'poiname' : 'FOUR CORNERS DAM', 'X':1.5778346701624997E7, 'y':-3861557.6243750006}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use regex for this, you don't need to parse the actual HTML (unless you need positional info as well):

```
import re

data = """
<div class="rbody">
<div style="color:#ff6666"> </div>
<i>objectid: </i> 137000<br/>
<i>topoid: </i> 504514394<br/>
<i>poigroup: </i> Hydrography<br/>
<i>poitype: </i> Manmade Waterbody<br/>
<i>poiname: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabel: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabeltype: </i> NAMED<br/>
<i>poialtlabel: </i> <br/>
<i>Point:</i><br/>
<i>X: </i> 1.5778346701624997E7 <br/>
<i>Y: </i> -3861557.6243750006 <br/>
<br/><br/>
</div>
"""

parsed = dict(element for element in re.findall(r"<i>\s*(.*?):.*?</i>\s*(.*?)\s*<br/>", data))
print(parsed)
# {'poigroup': 'Hydrography', 'objectid': '137000', 'topoid': '504514394', 'poilabeltype': 'NAMED', 'X': '1.5778346701624997E7', 'Point': '', 'poialtlabel': '', 'poitype': 'Manmade Waterbody', 'poiname': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM', 'poilabel': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM', 'Y': '-3861557.6243750006'}
```

You may need do additional post-processing if you want it to convert X and Y to floats, etc. For a universal solution you might want to try to convert each of the values, to something you can live with:

```
def conv(pair):
    if len(pair) < 2 or not pair[1]:
        return pair[0], None
    try:
        return pair[0], int(pair[1])
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return pair[0], float(pair[1])
        except ValueError:
            return pair

parsed = dict(conv(element) for element in re.findall(r"<i>\s*(.*?):.*?</i>\s*(.*?)\s*<br/>", data))
print(parsed)
# {'X': 15778346.701624997, 'Y': -3861557.6243750006, 'objectid': 137000, 'poilabeltype': 'NAMED', 'poialtlabel': None, 'poiname': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM', 'poitype': 'Manmade Waterbody', 'Point': None, 'poilabel': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM', 'topoid': 504514394, 'poigroup': 'Hydrography'}
```

How it works: simple, it 's searching between `<i>` and `<br/>` tags for two matching groups - one immediately after it, allowing whitespace, and one after `</i>` again allowing for whitespace. All such matches are captured, and looped over using the first captured group as a key and the second as a value for the new `dict`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I did try it. But it is throwing me a type error: expected string or a buffer.

Comment: I imagine you're passing your BS object instead of `data` in the examples above. Make sure you pass string data to it (for example, call on it `get_text()` first if applicable)...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = """<div class="rbody">
<div style="color:#ff6666"> </div>
<i>objectid: </i> 137000<br/>
<i>topoid: </i> 504514394<br/>
<i>poigroup: </i> Hydrography<br/>
<i>poitype: </i> Manmade Waterbody<br/>
<i>poiname: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabel: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
<i>poilabeltype: </i> NAMED<br/>
<i>poialtlabel: </i> <br/>
<i>Point:</i><br/>
<i>X: </i> 1.5778346701624997E7 <br/>
<i>Y: </i> -3861557.6243750006 <br/>
<br/><br/>
</div>"""

soup = Soup(html, 'html.parser')

obj = dict()
for i in soup.find_all('i'):
    key = str(i.get_text()).strip(' :')
    value = i.next_sibling
    if isinstance(value, NavigableString): # Check this because Point has not value.
        obj[key] = str(value).strip()
print(obj)
```

Note that the Point does not any value, so it needs a check if the next sibling is a string or not.

For more information check the [.next_sibling and .previous_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and how you can navigate through `tags` and `navigableStrings` with BeautifulSoup.

It prints the following with the help of BeautifulSoup only:

```
{
  'poilabeltype': 'NAMED',
  'objectid': '137000',
  'poilabel': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM',
  'poialtlabel': '',
  'poigroup': 'Hydrography',
  'Y': '-3861557.6243750006',
  'X': '1.5778346701624997E7',
  'poiname': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM',
  'poitype': 'Manmade Waterbody',
  'topoid': '504514394'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it but it is giving me an empty dictionary output.

Comment: Actually I'm using 2.7.x  .But I think the version should not make any difference.

Comment: The captured keys should be stripped off from the trailing colon and whitespace to match the OP's desired dictionary.

Comment: I edited the answer in order to work with python2 and remove whitespaces and `:` chars

Answer (score 0):

Well you can first [`decompose`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) the "br" tag from and use a the [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method to retrieve the `i` tag and the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the text after that tag.

```
In [81]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

In [82]: html = """<div class="rbody">
    ...: <div style="color:#ff6666"> </div>
    ...: <i>objectid: </i> 137000<br/>
    ...: <i>topoid: </i> 504514394<br/>
    ...: <i>poigroup: </i> Hydrography<br/>
    ...: <i>poitype: </i> Manmade Waterbody<br/>
    ...: <i>poiname: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
    ...: <i>poilabel: </i> FOUR CORNERS DAM<br/>
    ...: <i>poilabeltype: </i> NAMED<br/>
    ...: <i>poialtlabel: </i> <br/>
    ...: <i>Point:</i><br/>
    ...: <i>X: </i> 1.5778346701624997E7 <br/>
    ...: <i>Y: </i> -3861557.6243750006 <br/>
    ...: <br/><br/>
    ...: </div>"""

In [83]: soup = BS(html, "html.parser")

In [84]: for br in soup.select(".rbody > br"):
    ...:     br.decompose()
    ...:     

In [85]: {i.get_text(strip=True).replace(":", ""): i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select(".rbody > i")}
Out[85]: 
{'Point': '',
 'X': '1.5778346701624997E7',
 'Y': '-3861557.6243750006',
 'objectid': '137000',
 'poialtlabel': '',
 'poigroup': 'Hydrography',
 'poilabel': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM',
 'poilabeltype': 'NAMED',
 'poiname': 'FOUR CORNERS DAM',
 'poitype': 'Manmade Waterbody',
 'topoid': '504514394'}
```